# How to install pip for Python 3.7 on RHEL

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-3.7, rhel7

I am not able to find a repository for Python 3.7 with `pip` for RHEL. Please suggest one.

Answer (score -2):

Run these two simple commands:

```sh
$ sudo subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms
$ sudo yum install python37-python-pip
```

Source: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1519803

Comment: Were you able to successfully do this? Red Hat seems to have stopped updating SCL after Python 3.6.